# A jest worker process was terminated by another process

Tags: linux, jestjs

I am getting following error when I am building my application.

```
Test suite failed to run

  A jest worker process (pid=2439) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGKILL, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:366:23)
```

Can you please advice how to check OS logs on linux system and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A temporary workaround is running jest with these two arguments, `--runInBand --no-cache`, to run all tests in serial (slower) and to use a clean cache every time (also slower). But at least the tests run.

FYI, I'm using `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules` to use ESM modules with `ts-jest`. Not sure if that causes the instability.

Comment: ` --runInBand` solves the issue, no need for `--no-cache`, also `--experimental-vm-modules` is not needed unless u need to work with ESM

Answer (score 3):

Should be resolved by  https://github.com/jestjs/jest/pull/14015
Please update version of jest to latest and issue should be resolved.

Update:
If not working we found a workaround of adding and extra jest worker.
Refer to documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#maxworkers-number--string

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't solve the problem for us. Even with Jest 29.6.1 (the "fix" has been released in 29.6.0)

Comment: Apologies. We resolved the issue by adding an extra worker.

Comment: This is a workaround in the jest configuration file https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#maxworkers-number--string